# Laravel - How to chain Eloquent relationship - Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm using `Laravel 5.4`, `Laravel Roles` from [here](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-roles) and `Eloquent` relationships.

**I'm trying to retrieve the users of a company along with their roles.**

`User::find(1)->roles` gets me the user's roles whose `id =1`

`Company::find(1)->users` gets me all the users that belongs to the company whose `id =1` (without the roles of users).

`Company::find(1)->users->roles` returns an error `Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance.`

### Questions

1. Is it possible to do what I want to do ?
2. If so, how should I do it ?

---

#### User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoleAndPermission;

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

#### HasRoleAndPermission.php

```
trait HasRoleAndPermission
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(config('roles.models.role'));
    }
}
```

#### Company.php

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: `Company::with(['users', 'users.roles'])->find(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 company has many users.

1 users has many roles.

You are trying to get the roles of a collection of users (the property only exists for one user) thus, the property doesn't exists for the collection.

If you want to get all the roles of all users in the company, you might try the above code:

```
$roles = [];
Company::find(1)->users->foreach(function($user) {
    $roles = array_merge($roles, $user->roles);
});
```

--------- edit ---------

For eager loading the roles of users, you must use `with`, as suggested by  @Ohgodwhy, but I'd refactor a little:

```
$users = User::with('roles')->where('company_id', $companyId)->get();
```

Now you have the array of users eager loading their roles. You still can't access directly `$users->roles`, you must first get a `user`, only then get its `roles`.

Comment: What I would like to do is `Company::find(1)->users->roles` with users eager load their roles

Comment: So it needs there is no way to get what I want trough the `Company` model and not `User` one without getting `Company` info ?

Comment: I don't think so. If you start querying with the `Company` model, that is the model you will get in your response. If you really want what you asked in the question **I'm trying to retrieve the users of a company along with their roles.** then you query through the `User`, and only filter by the `Company`

Answer (score 4):

```
$company = Company::with('users.roles')->find(1);
```

Will load all the users, and all the roles for each user.

**Update**

According to your comment, you don't want the company data. Just users and roles Using eager loading and relationship existence.

```
$users = User::with('roles')
->whereHas('company' => function($query){
    $query->where('name', '=', 'company'); //If you don't have the company ID
})->get();
```

Without relationship existence

```
$users = User::where('company_id', 1)->with('roles')->get();
```

Comment: `Company::with('users.roles')->find(1)` works but it returns me the information of the company along with the one of the users. I did get the roles though but I would like to receive only the users with their roles not the company info.

Comment: So it needs there is no way to get what I want trough the `Company` model and not `User` one without getting `Company` info ?

Comment: No, because the company model returns a company or a collection of companies first. So if you use `Company::find()` or `first()` or `get()` you will always receive companies data.